# How do you find the inverse of $17x + 2$, to decode?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

Let's say I'm trying to encode "hi". "h" is $7$ and "i" is $8$. To encode it you do $17(7) + 2 = 119 \pmod {26} = 15$ which is "p", $17(8) + 2 = 138 \pmod {26} = 8$ which is "i".

Thus "hi" becomes "pi".

When I try to find the inverse it comes up as $\dfrac{x-2}{17}$, but let's say I'm trying to decode "pi". "p" is $15$ and "i" is $8$.

$\dfrac{15 - 2}{17} = 0.76 \pmod {26} = ? \\
\dfrac{8-2}{17} = 0.85 \pmod {26} = ?$

I't doesn't make sense. "pi" is supposed to go back to being "hi".

Comment: LaTeX the question please?

Comment: You must find the inverse $\mod 26$, not the inverse in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: What do you mean by $17(7)$ and $17(8)$? And what encryption / decryption scheme do you use? As it is now, the question is highly unclear.

Comment: h is "7" and "i" is 8 in the alphabet. I'm just plugging it into the equation 17x + 2. end because it's in the alphabet I have to use mod 26 to encode it.

Comment: $17\times 7 + 2 \equiv 17 \pmod{26}$, not $15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, compute $\gcd(17,26)$ by Euclidean algorithm.
$$9 = 26-17\quad\to\quad 8 = 17-9\quad\to\quad 1 = 9-8$$

Next, reverse the steps above and express $1$ as a linear combination of $17$ and $26$.
$$1 = 9 - 8 = 9 - (17-9) = -1\times 17 + 2\times 9
= -1\times 17 + 2\times(26-17)
= 2\times 26 -3\times 17
$$
Taking $\pmod{26}$ on both sides, we get
$$-3\times 17 \equiv 1\pmod{26}\quad\implies\quad 23\times 17\equiv 1 \pmod{26}$$
This means $17$ is invertible in modulus $26$ arithmetic with inverse $23$.

For "pi" = $(17, 8)$, when we apply the reverse operations, one get

$$
\begin{array}{cccl}
\textrm{p} = 17 & \leadsto & 17^{-1} \times (17-2) = 23\times (17-2) = 345 \equiv 7 \pmod {26} &\leadsto \textrm{h} \\
\textrm{i} = 8  & \leadsto & 17^{-1} \times (8-2) = 23\times (8-2)  = 138 \equiv 8 \pmod {26} &\leadsto 
\textrm{i}
\end{array}
$$
Please note that the $17^{-1}$ above stands for inverse of $17$ in the modulus 26 arithmetic, not the rational number $\frac{1}{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

Fill a map of the direct transform $(k,(17k+2)\bmod26)$ for $k\in[0,25]$, and sort it on the second number.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that "x" is the multiplicative inverse of 17, modulo 26, means that 17x= 1 (mod 26) which, in turn, means that 17x= 26k+ 1 for some integer k.  That is the same as the "Diophantine" equation, 17x- 26k= 1.   Now, 17 divides into 26 once with remainder 9: 26- 17= 9.  9 divides into 17 once with remainder 8: 17- 9= 8.  Finally, 8 divides into 9 with remainder 1: 9- 8= 1.  Replacing that 8 by 17- 9, 9- (17- 9)= 2(9)- 17= 1.  Replacing that 9 by 26- 17, 2(26- 17)- 17= 2(26)- 3(17)= 1.  So one solution is x= 3, k= 2. So 1/17= 3 (mod 26)- 3*17= 51= 2(26)+ 1.  The multiplicative inverse of 17, modulo 26, is 3.  From that, (15- 2)/17= 13*3= 39= 26+ 19= 13 (mod 26).  And (8- 2)/17= 6*3= 18 (mod 26).